# Ruby on rails .each method undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive an undefined method error on `each' for nil:NilClass.

The template:

```
<th>name></th>
<th>Comment</th>
<% @guests.each do |guest| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= guest.name %></td>
    <td><%= guest.comment %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @guest = Guest.all
  end

  def show
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @guest = Guest.new(article_params)

    @guest.save
    redirect_to @guest
  end

  private

  def article_params
   params.require(:guest).permit(:name, :email, :doctor, :Captain, :comment )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your `#index` method, replace `@guest` with `@guests`.

Like:

```
def index
  @guests = Guest.all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index` method you are using `@guest = Guest.all` and in your view file, you have specified `<% @guests.each do |guest| %>`. So you should change `@guests` to `@guest` in your view file.

Change this,

```
<% @guest.each do |guest| %>
```

in your view file

Answer (score 0):

You nowhere have `@guests`, in all of your methods you have `@guest`. This is why `@guests` has nill value, you have not define it.

Answer (score 0):

change your code is like this:

```
 def index
  @guests = Guest.all
 end
```

You are using @guests at view but in controller it is @guest

Comment: Thanks  for spotting the tucking fypos.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

This is error stating that, you are trying to use the `each` method of a `nil` object, that is you do not have anything defined as `@guests` in your `index` action.

You are actually trying to access the instance variable `@guest` of index action in your view.

So you need to fix the typo:

```
<% @guest.each do |guest| %> # you wrote @guests
```

*Suggestion: Since you are fetching all the guests, you should change your instance variable name from @guest to @guests to be more appropriate. In that case you do not have to change your view code. It will work as it is.*

```
def index
  @guests = Guest.all
end
```

Comment: @SeanpatrickMaiorca, it's good to do mistakes. We can only learn by doing mistakes and learning from them. :)